Error Implementing Amazon Appstore IAP - Fatal Error: Resource already registered: I5.f@4e905fb
I have an application published in Amazon appstore and also created in-app-purchase items for it in appstore of amazon. I have followed all the required steps to implement Amazon IAP in my app to purchase in-app consumables. I then implemented the code and created a live app testing in amazon appstore to test out the implementation of the code. But it gave me an error. I have given my code, and error below... please help me to solve it.
Amazon IAP Dependency:-
implementation("com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.+")

kotlin Activity Code:-
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.amazon.device.iap.PurchasingService
import com.amazon.device.iap.PurchasingListener
import com.amazon.device.iap.model.*
import com.fireframe.noxwallpapers.databinding.ActivityCreditsBinding
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar

class CreditsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityCreditsBinding
    private val purchasingListener = MyPurchasingListener()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityCreditsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        PurchasingService.registerListener(this, purchasingListener)

        val productSkus = setOf("50-nox-credits", "100-nox-credits", "200-nox-credits", "400-nox-credits")
        PurchasingService.getProductData(productSkus)

        binding.btnBuy50.setOnClickListener { purchaseProduct("50-nox-credits") }
        binding.btnBuy100.setOnClickListener { purchaseProduct("100-nox-credits") }
        binding.btnBuy200.setOnClickListener { purchaseProduct("200-nox-credits") }
        binding.btnBuy400.setOnClickListener { purchaseProduct("400-nox-credits") }
    }

    private fun purchaseProduct(sku: String) {
        PurchasingService.purchase(sku)
    }

    private inner class MyPurchasingListener : PurchasingListener {
        override fun onUserDataResponse(response: UserDataResponse?) {
            // Handle user data response
        }

        override fun onProductDataResponse(response: ProductDataResponse) {
            when (response.requestStatus) {
                ProductDataResponse.RequestStatus.SUCCESSFUL -> {
                    val products = response.productData
                    binding.btnBuy50.text = products["50-nox-credits"]?.price
                    binding.btnBuy100.text = products["100-nox-credits"]?.price
                    binding.btnBuy200.text = products["200-nox-credits"]?.price
                    binding.btnBuy400.text = products["400-nox-credits"]?.price
                }
                ProductDataResponse.RequestStatus.FAILED -> Log.e("IAP", "Failed to retrieve product data")
                else -> Log.e("IAP", "Unknown response status")
            }
        }

        override fun onPurchaseResponse(response: PurchaseResponse) {
            when (response.requestStatus) {
                PurchaseResponse.RequestStatus.SUCCESSFUL -> {
                    val receipt = response.receipt
                    handleReceipt(receipt)
                }
                PurchaseResponse.RequestStatus.FAILED -> Log.e("IAP", "Purchase failed")
                else -> Log.e("IAP", "Unknown purchase response status")
            }
        }

        override fun onPurchaseUpdatesResponse(response: PurchaseUpdatesResponse) {
            // Handle purchase updates if necessary
        }
    }

    private fun handleReceipt(receipt: Receipt) {
        val credits = when (receipt.sku) {
            "50-nox-credits" -> 50
            "100-nox-credits" -> 100
            "200-nox-credits" -> 200
            "400-nox-credits" -> 400
            else -> 0
        }
        addCredits(credits)
    }

    private fun addCredits(credits: Int) {
        Snackbar.make(binding.root,"Purchased $credits",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    companion object {
        const val SHARED_PREFS = "credits"
    }
}

Error Given When I have uploaded to amazon appstore in live testing to test it-out:-

FATAL EXCEPTION: main (Ask Gemini)
Process: com.fireframe.noxwallpapers, PID: 20346
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.fireframe.noxwallpapers/com.fireframe.noxwallpapers.CreditsActivity}:
B6.B: Resource already registered: I5.f@4e905fb
at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4164)
at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4322)
at
android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
at
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2685)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
Caused by: B6.B: Resource already registered: I5.f@4e905fb
at J1.b.a(SourceFile:89)
at z1.a.(SourceFile:124)
at z1.a.b(SourceFile:24)
at
com.fireframe.noxwallpapers.CreditsActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:385)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8975)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8944)
at
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4146)
at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4322) 
at
android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
at
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
at
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2685) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)


does the app run fine on a tablet or emulator?
